# How to get wifi password from gnome keyring file with a C program?

Tags: gnome-keyring, decryption

My system is Ubuntu 14.04. I know all passwords on my system.

I just want to write a C program, and to analysis the gnome keyring file in `/.local/share/keyrings/` for getting wifi password. I found "KeyringFormats" in [GnomeKeyringFormats](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/KeyringFormats/FileFormat), but I became confused after I read it.

I can find `GnomeKeyring\n\r\0\n` in the file header, but I can't find "2 byte version, 1 byte cryto, 1 byte hash",

I just find some zero. In addition, the "KeyringFormats" said "zero padding to make even multiple of 16", but the size of my "login.keyring" is 661 bytes.

I found some info in [SecurityFaq](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityFAQ). It said "SHA-256 for hashing, AES-128 for encrypting the secrets.", but it is too simple.

There is no problem for me to use AES-128 or SHA256.

The `nm-connection-editor` can show wifi password. I just want to write a C program like it.(no GUI)

Could anyone give me some suggestions or details about "KeyringFormats" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `man -k keyring`. It will show you, in part:

```
gnome-keyring-daemon (1) - keep password and other secrets for users
keyctl_clear (3)     - Clear a keyring
keyctl_get_keyring_ID (3) - Get the ID of a special keyring
keyctl_join_session_keyring (3) - Join a different session keyring
keyctl_link (3)      - Link a key to a keyring keyctl_unlink - Unlink a key from a keyring
keyctl_search (3)    - Search a keyring for a key
keyctl_session_to_parent (3) - Set the parent process's session keyring
keyctl_set_reqkey_keyring (3) - Set the implicit destination keyring
keyctl_unlink (3)    - Link a key to a keyring keyctl_unlink - Unlink a key from a keyring
recursive_key_scan (3) - Apply a function to all keys in a keyring tree
recursive_session_key_scan (3) - Apply a function to all keys in the session keyring tree
```

Read these `man` pages.

Comment: Thanks. I guss I should read source code for more details.